# Can you help me with this function? sec^2(x)-2=0

Tags: trigonometry

I don't know how to calculate the period of this function, can you help?
I already found that x=pi/4, and that's all. Please help!

Comment: Work with $cosine$ instead, I think you know some information about the period of cosine.

Comment: I tried that too, but when I use an identity formula, I get cos(x)=0. I know that the period is not 1pi, nor 2pi. :(

Comment: The period of cosine and sin is $2\pi$

Comment: I know, but sadly something's wrong :/

Comment: Which function? sec^2(x)-2=0 is no function.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{\cos^2 (x)}-2=0$$

$$\frac{1}{\cos^2 (x)}=2$$

$$\cos^2 (x)=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\cos (x)=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

$$\cos (x)=\pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

Look at the unit square when is cosine $\pm\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$? What other values of $x$ have the same $\cos(x)$ value?

[image]

Comment: For pi/4, I found that solution. I'm actually looking for the period, the interval between a new cycle begins.

Comment: What about $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ anything else..? The period of cosine is $2\pi$ because if you rotate a whole $360$ degrees your back to the same spot on the unit circle. @lola

Comment: I'm very lost. xD I need the part "a*pi*k"  I can't find the a :/